# mySQL Trigger after and before and sleep

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two trigger.
First trigger before, and  trigger after. I'm trying to delay the second trigger using SLEEP(20). Both trigger me but entries in the output table together at one time the delay of the 20s
How do I adjust the trigger to make it work independently?
thank you

Trigger 1

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `tr_inputEvent` BEFORE INSERT ON `modul_input_event`
FOR EACH ROW begin

UPDATE modul_io_register  SET pin7 = not(pin7) WHERE adresa = new.adresa and port = new.port;

END
//
```

Trigger 2

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `tr_inputEventSLEEP` AFTER INSERT ON `modul_input_event`
     FOR EACH ROW begin

    DO SLEEP(20);
    UPDATE modul_io_register  SET pin7 = not(pin7) WHERE adresa ='33' and port = 'A';

    END
    //
```